# How to fix a missing image

Tags: images

Someone made a website for me using wordpress.org. They said that they used "Wordpress Framework".

Although I haven't changed anything, the logo of the website (which was an image near the top of the homepage is now missing. Not sure how it could disappear without me changing anything, but I am trying to rectify this myself. I am not familiar with wordpress and so am hoping I can find some assistance; at least an idea of where to begin.

When I look what the active theme is, it just says 'Yescorts" which is the name of the website (yescorts.co.uk). I'm guessing that the creator customised an existing theme and then changed the name.

I know I will probably get down-voted for being vague, but if I knew enough to be specific, I would be able to fix this already. I'm just looking for some suggestions of where I start looking to fix this. Or what more info I can provide to help you help me.

Thanks in advance of any advice received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of your site shows that the HTML is referencing your developer's server for the logo. They must have cleaned up and deleted that server installation recently. 
You'll need to re-upload a logo to your own media library.

Comment: Thank you that's very helpful! I am assuming that I upload the image and then I need to change the HTML to point in the right direction?

Comment: You're welcome. Because it is WordPress you should have some UI field in the theme to re-upload the image and it "just works" (like uploading a new fb profile pic). Editing HTML directly is usually not needed in WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Most themes have a 'set site header' type option in the Theme Customizations.

You could also use developer tools (like Firebug); look at the 'Net' tab to see what file is returning a 404 (not found).

Could be that the file being accessed is missing from your Media folder. Upload it again, then use Theme Customizations to specify the newly uploaded-into-Media image.